# MYSQL Query takes too much time when using where, group by and order by

Tags: php, mysql

I have debugging a MYSQL query which is taking too much time.

The Query is like this:

```
SELECT *, TM.tutor_id as tutor_id, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE( ) ) AS age 
FROM tutor_master as TM 
LEFT JOIN category_master as CM on CM.category_id=TM.category 
LEFT JOIN tutor_expected_rate TER ON FIND_IN_SET(TER.tutor_id, TM.tutor_id) > 0 
LEFT JOIN admin_shortlist_master SHM ON TM.tutor_id = SHM.tutor_id 
    AND (SHM.user_auth_id = 'c84258e9c39059a89ab77d846ddab909') 
LEFT JOIN level_master LM ON FIND_IN_SET(LM.level_id, TER.level_id) > 0 
WHERE 1=1 
GROUP BY TM.tutor_id 
order by TM.is_priority DESC, TM.tutor_id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

If I am excluding the part

```
WHERE 1=1 
GROUP BY TM.tutor_id 
ORDER BY TM.is_priority DESC, TM.tutor_id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

The Query is executed like this:

> Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 27,649 total, Query took 0.2339 sec)

for the Full Query it is like this:

> Showing rows 0 - 9 ( 10 total, Query took 115.4066 sec)

I have it indexed for all the fields used in the query.

The MYSQL explain is like this:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE           TM     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    27530   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE           CM     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   toprecru_portal_db.TM.category  1   
1   SIMPLE          TER     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    13223   
1   SIMPLE          SHM     ref     tutor_id,user_auth_id   user_auth_id    257     const   1   
1   SIMPLE           LM     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    11
```

update:

I read somewhere that using 1=1 doesn't have performance impact, but even when adding 1=1 the query takes around 70 seconds from 0.2339 seconds.

MYSQL my.cnf setting are like this:

```
read_buffer_size = 512M
join_buffer_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
```

Update:

when using group_by without order_by the time is almost the same like:

> Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 27,530 total, Query took 114.9642 sec)

update sample date:
Table - Tutor Expected Rate

```
id      tutor_id    level_id    exp_rate
1        27597         4    $30-35/hr
2        27597        10    $40-45/hr
99       27598         5    35-40/hr minimum
124      27602         4    25-30/hr or 30-40/hr minimum 1.5hrs per session
125      27602         0
```

Table - admin_shortlist_master

```
admin_shortlist_id  job_ad_id   request_profile_id  tutor_id    user_auth_id    added_date
143693                 0              0              22692  4ef44ea2203114a3e27eaff31a1bf3be    2015-09-17
143694                 0              0              11653  4ef44ea2203114a3e27eaff31a1bf3be    2015-09-17
143695                 0              0              27611  4ef44ea2203114a3e27eaff31a1bf3be    2015-09-17
143696                 0              0              27610  4ef44ea2203114a3e27eaff31a1bf3be    2015-09-17
296793                 0             13                0    21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3    2015-10-05
```

table-  category master

```
category_id     category_name          disp_order   status 0-Not Published, 1-Published
1               Polytechnic Student     0                1
2               Diploma Grad Part Time  1                1
3               Diploma Grad Full Time  2                1
4               JC Student              3                0
5               A Level Grad Part Time  4                1
```

table - level master

```
level_id    level_name           class_title    class_ids         subject_ids   status 0-Not Published, 1-Published
4           Primary              Primary        4,5,6,7,8,9,10      5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15    1
5           O Level (Secondary)  Secondary      12,13,14,15,16  
4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24...   1
6           A Level (JC)         JC             18,19,20    6,17,18,19,23,24,25,26,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,...   1
7           International Baccalaureate             17,18,19,23,24,34,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50...   1
8           Diploma             26,34,47,54,55,56,57,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68...   1
```

UPDATE:

```
select tutor_id, category, is_priority, birthdate from tutor_master order by tutor_id limit 5
tutor_id Ascending 1    category    is_priority     birthdate
4                          8              0         1989-01-01
7                          8              0         1987-01-01
8                          8              0         1964-01-01
9                          2              0         1987-01-01
10                         8              0         1983-01-01
```

Comment: @Bamar - Actually I am debugging someone else's query. and I am wondering why it is used like that as in those columns there is no comma separated values is there. but having said that, even using that if I am not using where, group by and order by, the speed is quite good.

Comment: That's why I deleted my comment, I didn't see that part of the question before.

Comment: What happens if you just use `GROUP BY` without `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @Barmar - update the question for your query.

Comment: @Pawan why are you using 1 = 1 in where clause. and Also I am not sure why are using group by as well.

Comment: @FahadAnjum - The query is dynamic for example, there may be other clauses added in the query in the where clause like `and where race=1` and it may not be there. so the query will not end up like `and where`

Comment: @Pawan I also wonder why you're using `GROUP BY`, since you don't have any aggregation functions like `SUM()` or `COUNT()`.

Comment: As well as the EXPLAIN, questions about query performance always require require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables - especially so where columns in the query are unqualified

Comment: Mysql, by default, allows a non-standard use of group by. This query demonstrates  that use of group by and the impact is similar to that of using "select distinct", which when combined with "select *" is a very poor practice .

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of difficult to debug without knowing the table structure and having some sample data (if you could edit your original question to include these it'd help). It seems your biggest issue is the lack of indicies on all tables.

You should be able to get an output like this where everything is using an index:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | TM    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                     |    2 | Using temporary; Using filesort                              |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | CM    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 4       | tutors.TM.category       |    1 | Using index                                                  |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | TER   | index  | NULL          | tutor_id | 8       | NULL                     |    1 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | SHM   | eq_ref | tutor_id      | tutor_id | 606     | tutors.TM.tutor_id,const |    1 | Using where; Using index                                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | LM    | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY  | 4       | NULL                     |    1 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Because you're using `FIND_IN_SET` you likely won't be able to remove the join buffers and it seems to always require a full table scan of tutors which shouldn't be an issue.

These are the indicies I have for all tables:

```
MariaDB [tutors]> show indexes from admin_shortlist_master;
+------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| admin_shortlist_master |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| admin_shortlist_master |          0 | tutor_id |            1 | tutor_id     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| admin_shortlist_master |          0 | tutor_id |            2 | user_auth_id | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------------------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tutors]> show indexes from category_master;
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| category_master |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | category_id | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tutors]> show indexes from level_master;
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| level_master |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | level_id    | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tutors]> show indexes from tutor_expected_rate;
+---------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table               | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tutor_expected_rate |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tutor_expected_rate |          0 | tutor_id |            1 | tutor_id    | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tutor_expected_rate |          0 | tutor_id |            2 | level_id    | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to provide your overall structure and some sample data then there is likely a way to index the `tutor_master` table as well, but it's difficult to determine at the moment.

Comment: There is not data for `tutor_master` which is the only questionable table

Comment: That table `tutor_master` is very difficult to reproduce here, it contains around 150 fields.

Comment: Then the indexes provided will probably be the most efficient since it makes every table in the query use an index.

Comment: I don't know but yes index on `tutor_id` and `level_id` for `tutor_expected_rate` was not there. I have added that. It speed up the query drastically if I alter the part `LEFT JOIN tutor_expected_rate TER ON FIND_IN_SET(TER.tutor_id, TM.tutor_id) > 0` to `LEFT JOIN tutor_expected_rate TER ON TER.tutor_id= TM.tutor_id`. I cannot see any apparent change on the result set. 
Can you have a look if it can alter the result set with the changes.

Comment: without those changes it is still taking 120 seconds, but with those changes, it is reduced to below 2 seconds.

Comment: Can you dump out 5 rows for `tutor_master` columns `tutor_id`, `category`, `is_priority` and `birthdate` as these seems to be the columns that are used in the query

Comment: Added the dump for `tutor_master` for 5 rows

Comment: The data doesn't line up, for example `category` 8 isn't in `category master` but it's in 4 of the `tutor_master` rows. Let me know if you can provide 5 rows that all match up, otherwise it's almost impossible to test.